# Overview over the iterator requirements of various algorithms

Tags: c++, iterator

Does anyone know of a source that gives an overview of the requirements regarding `iterator_category` posed by various algorithms in the C++ standard library? The documentation I've seen only gives the required `iterator_category` for each specific algorithm, not an overview of all algorithms.

Specifically, I am looking for cases where a `bidirectional_iterator` is needed where a `forward_iterator` wouldn't do.

Comment: Would be better if you narrow to specific algorithms.

Comment: @40two I don't have a specific algorithm in mind. I've just got a data structure for which I can implement forward iterators fairly easily, and bidirectional iterators with a lot more work. I'm wondering if that extra work is likely to be useful, and if so, for what kind of operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching for "Bidirectional" in Clause 25 gives:

- `std::copy_backward`
- `std::move_backward`
- `std::reverse`
- `std::reverse_copy`
- `std::stable_partition`
- `std::inplace_merge`
- `std::next_permutation`
- `std::prev_permutation`

In general, you can consult the `<algorithm>` synopsis in §25.1 [algorithms.general] of the standard.

Answer (score 0):

The standard lays out the requirements for the various iterators, with the relevant section being §24.2 [iterator.requirements].

As to your question specifically with regard to bidirectional iterators, they are required whenever it is necessary to move an iterator backwards, since they support every operation supported by forward iterators, in addition to:

```
--i
i--
*i--
```

[As detailed here.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator)